# Member variables of pointer changing for some reason?

Tags: c++, pthreads, member-variables

I am running a thread for a scheduler and am inserting processes into the queue of the scheduler in the main thread while the scheduler thread is still running. For whatever reason the variables of the process object are changing when the object itself is passed into the ReadyQueue. For example, I pass in 100 msBurstTime and when I print it in the thread it says it is 32571.
Here is the scheduler code for thread execution:

```
void Scheduler::startThread(CPU *cpu, IO_manager *io_m){
    this->link(cpu, io_m);
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, Scheduler::staticThreadEntry, this);
}

void Scheduler::FCFS(){
    while (true){
        sleep(2);
        if (this->ReadyQueue.size() > 0 && cpu->getRunningProcess() == NULL){
            std::cout << this->ReadyQueue.at(0) << ' ';
            // burst time out of whack here (32571 ms)
            std::cout << this->ReadyQueue.at(0)->getBurstTime() << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "Dispatched process" << std::endl;
            //this->dispatchProcess();
        }
        //std::cout << "CPU occupied" << std::endl;
    }
}

void* Scheduler::staticThreadEntry(void *self){
    ((Scheduler*) self)->FCFS();
}
```

And here is where I am inserting a process into the ReadyQueue of the scheduler:

```
void Scheduler::insertProcess(Process *p){
    // burst time fine here (100 ms)
    this->ReadyQueue.push_back(p);
}
```

Here is what is called in main.cpp to init the scheduler:

```
scheduler.startThread(&cpu, &io_m);
```

and here is what is called in main.cpp to insert a process into the ReadyQueue of the scheduler:

```
if (strcmp(args[0], "newp") == 0){
    // args[1] is process status, args[2] is ms burst time
    Process p(stoi(args[1]), stoi(args[2]));
    scheduler.insertProcess(&p);
}
```

Why is this happening? I check the references of the process object and it is the same instance, so why are the member variables changing?

Comment: `p` gets destroyed at the closing `}`.

Comment: And in addition to that, there does not seem to be any kind of locking or thread-safe access to the shared `ReadyQueue`, whatever that is. Open your C++ book to the chapter on multithreaded programming, and learn how to use mutexes and condition variables. And it will also be a good idea to use C++11's `std::thread` instead of POSIX threads.

Comment: Wow I didn't fully understand how pointer's worked apparently. Just needed to pass a copy of the object inside the function instead of using pointers at all. I was going to implement locks as necessary but I wanted to keep it simple until I figured this one out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strcmp(args[0], "newp") == 0){
    // args[1] is process status, args[2] is ms burst time
    Process p(stoi(args[1]), stoi(args[2]));
    scheduler.insertProcess(&p);
}
```

You've asked the `scheduler` to store a pointer to an object, `p`, that is about to stop existing. There is nothing useful you can do with a pointer to an object that no longer exists.

It's almost never sensible to use a collection of raw pointers. It makes it unclear what owns the object and how the object's lifetime is managed. Use values if possible. Otherwise, think about `std::unique_ptr` or, if necessary, `std::shared_ptr`.